# Understanding threading in asp.net and how server memory is allocated

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, caching, memory

If for instance, 3 requests are made to the server, does that mean 3 instances of the web application are put into memory?

What if you used a locked singleton or cached a class so each time it checks to see if the object exists or not and creates the object if it doesn't exist, does that mean that the object is cached for each request? or is it cached once and reused for each request?

If I locked a singleton, does that mean The object using the singleton is created once and each request uses the same object? or does it mean the object is created using the singleton for each request but is not created again by the same thread?

If I used `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache["key"];`
to cache a 1 mb object and 10 requests are made, am I using up 10 mb's of memory on the server? if I created a new object using a singleton... what occurs in terms of threading and memory allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS an AppDomain is created for each Application and will share a process with other applications in the same AppPool.

So 3 requests to the server within the same Web Application will share the same AppDomain.

How that affects caching and singletons:

From the docs on [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx):

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active.

When you lock an object (like a singleton) the lock's scope is an AppDomain as well.

Comment: So when is an AppDomain created? when a user makes a request?

Comment: When I say locked singleton I mean when it is implmented like this:  public static T GetInstance()
        {
            lock (typeof(T))
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new T();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

Comment: On first request after app pool restart. And beware of static properties or singletons. In multi-server environment (webfarm) there will be as many static objects or singletons as number of nodes you have.

Comment: @user1809104 Yes the first request will cause an AppDomain to be created.  Also shutting down or restarting an AppPool (which can happen automatically after periods of inactivity) will start the process over.

Comment: @user1809104 I have edited my post to answer the `lock` question

Comment: Thanks Stanley. When user "a" makes a request an appdomain is created, the web app runs for that user, singletons in the app that are applied to objects only apply to THAT user, the instantiated object can't be accessed by any other user is that right? So when when user "b" comes along a NEW appdomain is created for user "b" and and instance of the app is PUT INTO MEMORY while creating its own object instances within the web app? So when user "a" makes ANOTHER request, user "a" still uses the SAME appdomain that the user used before. If that scenario is correct. When is the appdomain destroye?

Comment: No, that is not right.  Only one AppDomain is created PER APPLICATION and is shared by all users.  The AppDomain is destroyed when the App Pool is recycled (either manually or after a period of inactivity configures within IIS.

Comment: If you want to cache data for a _user_ use `Session` instead.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted. So If I cached a 1 meg item and ten users signed in I will have only used one mb of server memory... Do you know of any books or links to information on this subject? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yours instance - process and yours 3 requests - executed by threads. So singleton object will be shared between all 3 requests. Your cache also will be shared between requests. In your example you will allocate only 1 Mb (it will update 10 times). Garbage collector will collect unused space.